# ( HTML / CSS ) I don`t know how to build page responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riW2r.jpg)

does anyone know how to do it right ?
when i use responsive in chrome , the photo is on top of the text at 1000 pixels.

i have html: `

```
        <div class="fans-inner ">

            <div class="account acc-left">
                <img class="account-logo" src="./img/man.png" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="block-coments">
                <p class="coments">
                    Consectetur adipiscing elit,
                    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore 
                    et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut 
                    aliquip ex ea commodo core dot occaecat cupidatat 
                    non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia borum.
                </p>
            </div>
    
        </div>

        <div class="fans-inner ">

            <div class="block-coments">
                <p class="coments">
                    Consectetur adipiscing elit,
                    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore 
                    et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut 
                    aliquip ex ea commodo core dot occaecat cupidatat 
                    non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia borum.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="account acc-right">
                <img class="account-logo" src="./img/man.png" alt="">
            </div>

        </div>
        

    </div>

</section>`
```

css : `

```
       .fans-inner {
         display: flex;
         justify-content: center;
         position: relative;
        }
      .account {
         position: absolute;
      }

       .block-coments {
          max-width: 800px;
       }

       coments {
           margin-left: 40px;
           margin-right: 40px;
           padding: 25px;
           background-color: #f2f2f5;
           margin-bottom: 20px;
       }

       .acc-left {
           left: 10%;
       }
       .acc-right {
           right: 10%;
       }`
```

should I put them at 1000px below the text?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzXMt.png)
if I put Left: 0, Right: 0 the pictures are too far away from text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make a page responsive use @media queries and mention how the page should look if the screen size is less than 1000px, less than 750px, etc.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  /* write your css rules here */
}
```

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries